# Could not find member 'setObject' : NSMutableDictionary

Tags: ios, swift

I've declared variable as

```
var optionDictionary : NSMutableDictionary!
```

try to set object for this variable in function, but got error

> Could not find member 'setObject'

```
func setOptionSetting()
{
    self.optionDictionary = NSMutableDictionary() // No Error
    self.optionDictionary!.setObject(NSNumber(int:Integer_Constant)!, forKey: "Key_Constant") // here, I got error..
    ....
}
```

Please anyone find this, please describe with brief-explanation..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seppo's answer is correct, but you don't even need to create an `NSNumber`:

```
self.optionDictionary["Key_Constant"] = Integer_Constant
```

Answer (score 1):

What if you just did the following?

```
self.optionDictionary[AVFormatIDKey] = NSNumber(int:TFORMAT_ID)
```

Comment: This is too not working but when I change this into `self.optionDictionary[AVFormatIDKey] = NSNumber(integer:TFORMAT_ID)` working good. Anyway for your hint, +1 to you.